# change chart attributes using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm retrieving the source of the following url: http://www.google.com/finance?q=EPA:RNO
using urllib2.

The problem is the default settings for the chart will exclude some data to be placed in the page source. Therefore, I need to interact with the page before I retrieve the source.

With default settings, if you look below this line

```
<span class=settings-link>Settings</span>
```

you have

```
_chartConfigObject.defaultInterval = '86400';
```

I need to chage this to

```
_chartConfigObject.defaultInterval = '1800';
```

Can I do this using Selenium? Is there another way, i.e. using the default settings saved in my browser cookie to automatically set the right interval before retrieving the url source?

Answer (score 0):

There is a relevant URL parameter `chddi` that controls the used interval:

```
https://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=Linear&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1415318689290&chddm=5210&chddi=1800&chls=CandleStick&q=EPA:RNO&ntsp=0&ei=hgxcVIDZDIuMqQHDmYDoCg
```

How I've got this URL? I've just set the desired chart settings and clicked "Link to this view" button that generated the URL.

You can though utilize selenium and control the chart settings, example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


url = 'http://www.google.com/finance?q=EPA:RNO'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

settings = driver.find_element_by_class_name('settings-link')
settings.click()

candlestick = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="CandleStick"]')
candlestick.click()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('defaultInterval'))
select.select_by_value('1800')
```